# npm install from bitbucket with team name in git url

Tags: git, npm, bitbucket

I have created a bitbucket repository, and now I want to install it as a dependency in my node js project. I have also created a password app, and installed the package like so:

```
npm i --save git+https://MyUser:MyAppPassword@bitbucket.org/MyCompany/my-repository.git
```

This works fine, but the problem is that I am part of a team (to which MyUser belongs), and I do not want the git URL to contain MyUser, but instead the name of the team. How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "MyUser" part listed there is the name used for authentication and authorization. Your coworkers can provide their own credentials if they'd prefer, or you can set up an access key and use SSH instead, but there's no way for the team to authenticate.